# jQuery ":contains" alternative for a links

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a selector in jQuery - :contains

Example:

```
str = 'test';
blocked_div = $(".mydiv:contains("+str+")");
blocked_div.find('img').hide();
...
<a href="http://example.com">test</a>
...
```

As I understand it's search for a "test" text inside a ".mydiv" element.
But now i need to find a link "http://example.com" inside a ".mydiv" element, and :contains dont work in this situation. Can you recommend a solution to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
$(".mydiv a[href='example.com']");
```

You can also use `*=` or `^=` filters to find links which contain specified text anywhere or at start of string respectively.

```
// find links containing "example" in href at any place
$(".mydiv a[href*='example']");
```

For your `str` variable, you can modify it like:

```
$('.mydiv a[href=' + str + ']'); // exact match
$('.mydiv a[href*=' + str + ']'); // contains str anywhere in href
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to test whether the string is contained in the HREF? This ought to do it:

```
$('.mydiv a[href~='+str+']');
```

The `~=` means the attribute on the left contains the string on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Change the selector like following:

```
var str = 'test';
$(".mydiv a:contains("+str+")").attr('href'); // return `href` attribute of that `a`
                                              // contains string test
```

To get the link with specific `href`

```
var str = 'http://example.com';
$(".mydiv a[href="'+ str+ '"]");
```

Comment: That's checking the text; he's asking how to check the href.